# Windows Phone 8: How to Bind from ICollection

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I'm on windows phone 8 project and i'm new on this platform.

I was doing binding from xaml side very well but i generated another new web api classes and i couldn't bind any item from ICollection.

Here is my webapi.cs class ;

```
    public class General
            {
                public Team Team { get; set; }
                public int Position { get; set; }
                public int LastPosition { get; set; }
                public int Played { get; set; }
                public int Won { get; set; }
                public int Draw { get; set; }
                public int Lost { get; set; }
                public int Scored { get; set; }
                public int Against { get; set; }
                public int Average { get; set; }
                public double Points { get; set; }
                public int SetsWon { get; set; }
                public int SetsLost { get; set; }
                public int SetAverage { get; set; }
                public double WinningPercentage { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public double? GamesBehind { get; set; }
            }
 public class Team
        {
            public int Sport { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ShortName { get; set; }
            public bool HasLogo { get; set; }
        }
        public class LeagueName
                {
                    public Stage Stage { get; set; }
                    public List<General> General { get; set; }
                    public List<Home> Home { get; set; }
                    public List<Away> Away { get; set; }
                    public GroupedRows GroupedRows { get; set; }
                    public GroupedRowsHome GroupedRowsHome { get; set; }
                    public GroupedRowsAway GroupedRowsAway { get; set; }
                    public List<GroupType> GroupTypes { get; set; }
                    public List<string> Descriptions { get; set; }
                }

                public class RootObject
                {
                    public ICollection<LeagueName> LeagueNames { get; set; }
                }
```

And here is how am i trying to bind ;

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="LeagueTable"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" DataContext="{Binding LeagueNames}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding General.Position}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding General.Played}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

But in debug mode, it always says this error when i click related place;

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'General' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=17778899). BindingExpression: Path='General.Position' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=17778899); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

Please help me about it people.
Thank you too much.

**UPDATE**

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="WinPhone8try1.LeagueDetail"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    DataContext="{Binding LeagueName[]}">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <ListBox x:Name="LeagueTable"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding General.Position}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding General.Played}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          </ListBox >
    </Grid>

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_back.png" Text="Geri" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I made the bindings like this. There is no error but nothing is displaying on screen. Can you help me about it please my friend ?

**UPDATE 2**

```
<ListBox x:Name="LeagueTable"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding General[]}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Team.Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Team.Played}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          </ListBox>
```

namespace WinPhone8try1
{
    public partial class LeagueDetail : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private string json = "";
        private LeagueDetailApi.LeagueName[] leaguedetail { get; set; }

```
    public LeagueDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LeagueDetailApi.LeagueName();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = NavigationContext.QueryString["selectedIndex"];
        int index = int.Parse(selectedItem);
        string url = "MY API URL;
        HttpWebRequest hWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        hWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        hWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(LeagueTable_Load_Completed, hWebRequest);
    }

    private void LeagueTable_Load_Completed(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(ar);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            leaguedetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueDetailApi.LeagueName[]>(json);
        }
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                                      {
                                                          LeagueTable.DataContext =
                                                              leaguedetail.ToList();
                                                      });
    }

    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
DataContext="{Binding LeagueName}"
```

Should be

```
DataContext="{Binding LeagueNames}"
```

Comment: nope, that doesnt solve the problem, thanks anyways. any other advice ?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `StackPanel`'s `DataContext` to a collection of `LeagueName`, each `LeagueName` has a *list* of `General`. So you have to either bind the list again, or choose one of the instances, e.g if you want the first general:

[EDIT]

I misread the question at first. You can't bind a collection to stack panel. You can bind the `DataContext` (as you did), but it won't help you. You either have to use nested list-like containers or select one of the `LeagueName`s, same as for `General`. So, you need nested lists.

For all of them, you can use e.g. `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LeagueTable"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" ItemsSource="{Binding LeagueNames}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding General}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Played}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox >
```

Comment: "
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'General' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=15047603). BindingExpression: Path='General' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=15047603); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable').."

Comment: @kgms21 Check the edit. I've checked it on a new WP8 project just to be sure, it should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer my friend. I will be able to try this answer on monday. I hope it will help me and i will accept this as an answer. thanks

Comment: me,i've tried and; BindingExpression path error: 'LeagueNames' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FanatikWinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FanatikWinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=48873995). BindingExpression: Path='LeagueNames' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FanatikWinPhone8try1.Apis.LeagueDetailApi+LeagueName]' (HashCode=48873995); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' (Name='LeagueTable'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')..

Comment: Is your `RootObject` bound to the `DataContext` of the page? Because it has to be...

Comment: @kgms21 If you're not using any MVVM framework, then you should do this in the code behind of the page: `DataContext = new RootObject()`. Then you can bind the `ListBox` `ItemsSource` to the list.

Comment: How can i use MVVM fw ? Or for this situation, what will be the code behind in mainpage.xaml.cs ? After  InitializeComponent(); function ? Can you help me please ? Whats the code gonna be ?

Comment: @kgms21 Yep, after `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor you can assign the right view model to the `DataContext`

Comment: Mate, seriously, i couldnt solve this problem. i couldnt look the project for a wile but i couldnt solve that..can you check the edit please..see what i've tried.